# jmeter http request no value, but wrong name

Tags: jmeter

I create a jmeter http request
with parameter name & value.
While the test result is no value only the parameter names.(parameter names are wrong :(

[parameters config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xNdgN.jpg)

[error result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3WcK7.jpg)

```
POST http://localhost:8080/aqnu/loginsys

POST data:
200117003200117003

Cookie Data:
JSESSIONID=438A7FCE7211763AFFF57F89F5A9FCB3

Request Headers:
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: http://localhost:8080/aqnu/login
Accept-Language: zh-CN,zh;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,zh-TW;q=0.7
Origin: http://localhost:8080
DNT: 1
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
```

Answer (score 0):

1. It might be the case with the parameters themselves, i.e. if you copied and pasted them from some source the parameters may include non-printable special characters like [line breaks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) therefore JMeter fails to properly parse them in `HTML` mode. Try switching to `Raw` and see how does your request look like there
2. If the cause is different unfortunately we will not able to help without seeing the logs. If you want to check it out yourself or update the question with the logs:

   - Add the next lines to *log4j2.xml* file

     ```
     <Logger name="org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http" level="debug" />
     <Logger name="org.apache.http" level="debug" />
     <Logger name="org.apache.http.wire" level="error" />
     ```

     These lines will [increase JMeter logs verbosity](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging) for [HTTP protocol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Overview)
   - Restart JMeter to pick up the changes
   - Search for your request parameters in [*jmeter.log*](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/hints_and_tips.html#debug_logging) file an see how do they look like.

Comment: i am really type the parameters 2 twice, and this `Sample Http Request` generated by `Test Script Recorder`, i only change the values.